# Заблокировать доступ к просмотру файлов в директориях сайта и отдавать в ответ ошибку 404

Tags: .htaccess, apache, seo, http-status-code-404

Здравствуйте. Проблема в том, что яндекс индексирует ссылки типа "site.ru/images/", "site.ru/css/" и т.д. хотя в каталоге images или css нет index.php файлов. В .htaccess закрыл доступ к просмотру файлов в каталоге прописав "Options -Indexes". Как ко всему это добавить еще код ошибки 404? Спасибо.

Comment: Вот такая штука не работает  RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^\/(images)
RewriteRule .* - [L,R=404]     потому как закрывается доступ как к каталогу images так и к файлу images.php

Comment: Много 404 по внутренним ссылкам сайта - очень плохо для позиции в выдаче поисковика. Используяте robots.txt

Answer (score 0):

Добавить в `site.ru/robots.txt`:

```
User-Agent: *
Disallow: /images/
Disallow: /css/
```

Это запретит всем поисковикам и роботам обращаться ко всему содержимому указанных каталогов. Но браузеры по прежнему смогут получать файлы из этих каталогов.

Answer (score 0):

В справке **[Яндекс Вебмастер Использование HTML-элементов](https://yandex.ru/support/webmaster/controlling-robot/html.html)**, сообщается:

> `<meta name="robots" content="noindex"/>` — не индексировать текст страницы

Вы можете применить этот мета атрибут для запрета индексации требуемых ссылок.

Если у вас имеется **[собственная веб-страница 404](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/93641)** (Гугл рекомендует), то для htaccess вы можете применить следующую строчку:

```
ErrorDocument 404 https://вебсайт.com/404.html
```